# Cypress CI/CD with NextJS and GitLab throws heap error when starting server

Tags: next.js, cypress, gitlab-ci

sorry if this question has already been answered but I am struggling to find answers as there seem to be a million ways to do this, but none seem to integrate the server.

As the title suggests, I am looking for a way to integrate my Cypress E2E tests into my CI/CD pipeline on GitLab.

I have actually done the above, but I get an error in my logs saying:

```
FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
```

I am starting a dev server using `npm run dev` as part of my CI/CD pipeline.

`gitlab-ci.yml` looks like the following:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

build: 
  stage: build
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.2-slim-chrome100-ff99-edge
  script:
    - npm install --frozen-lockfile
  

test:
  image: cypress/browsers:node16.14.2-slim-chrome100-ff99-edge
  stage: test
  script:
    # install dependencies
    - npm ci
    # run Cypress tests
    - npm run test:cypress
```

with the above `test:cypress` command looking like the following (in `package.json`)

```
"test:cypress": "npm run setup:cypress:environment && npx cypress run",
"setup:cypress:environment": "dotenv -e .env.test -- npm run dev & wait-on http://localhost:3000",
```

Now i know that many of the examples create a test server, which is where I am stuck. How to create a test server in NextJS, and mock the DB connections?

Any help is greatly appreciated.